# PhpStorm 6 crashing and going out of memory when there is symlink in project?

Tags: php, phpstorm

My installation pf PhpStorm keeps crashing when I open a directory that has a symlink to another directory in the project. For example, my project has `dir1, dir2 and dir3`. In `dir3` I have a symlink o `dir2`. When I try to expand `dir3` PhpStorm keeps going out of memory and eventually crashing. I increased to 1 GB and still it crashes. I know it is not a memory issue but tired increasing it anyway. I am on a Mac Mountain lion. Has anybody experienced this before? If so what are my options?

Comment: PHPStorm probably creates an endless recursion when indexing files. That may be a bug, and should be reported: http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/anonymous_requests/new

Comment: I reported it http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20075 with the stack dump. But it does not happen to my team mates, which puzzles me.

Comment: Are they also on Macs?

Comment: Is dir3 *inside* dir2? Does dir2 contain a symlink to dir3? You need to explain your folder structure better.

Comment: I was able to get around this by removing the project files in my project root and then add the project again. Then immediately exclude the directory. I tried doing this before but did not work until I reimported the project again. I also updated the jdk.
@Sammitch dir3 and dir2 are on the same level but in dir3 there is a symlink to dir3 which was causing phpstorm to go into infinite recursion when I try to expand dir3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using version 7. I have also found that WebStorm indexes symlinks recursively, which is bad if they ever point to their parents - indexing just goes on forever until out of memory.

One manual fix for this is to exclude any folders that are pointing to parents:

[image]

However, this is inefficient, as WebStorm should be smart enough to do it by itself, and an oversight can easily lead to crashing and running out of memory. This comes up a lot when using frameworks with auto-build features such as [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com).

Ultimately, this should be reported as a bug. This is just a workaround.